# Setting a divs background image using jquery in IE 6 and 7

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, background-image

Hi i am trying to apply a background image to a div using jquery.  The code i use works fine in all browsers except IE 6 and 7 (the weakest browsers i need to support).  If I statically apply a style tag to my div, it does show the image but when i apply it using jquery it does not.  I am using IE Tester to test in IE 6 and 7.  When I look at the interpreted source code it shows a style attribute with the correct background property on the correct tag.

here is the code i use

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
```

JQuery:

```
var img-src = 'url('+$('.img-src').text()+')';
$('.overlay').css('background-image', img-src);
```

note: i've also tried using the key 'backgroundImage' instead of 'background-image' as a parameter to the css function.  Using background-image is what got it to appear in IE 8.  Has anyone faced a similar problem and know a work around?

UPDATE:  The image i am trying to make appear actually does appear in IE 6, now it's just IE 7 that's giving me trouble.

Comment: Your code is invalid. A variable may not be named `img-src` (replace the dash with an underscore).

Comment: my variable's name in the actual code is not img-src.  I changed the name to comply with my company's confidentiality policy.  The real variables name is a single word without any hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.overlay').css('background-image', $('.img-src').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$('.overlay').css('background', img-src + ' no-repeat top left');
```